# Ruby on Rails: Saving user id manually? Or is there a better method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Should I manually add a user_id into the hidden form? Or is there a better way?

I have models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end
```

In my view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :value => current_user.id %>
<% end %>
```

Or is there another way to do this? I thought if the model was associated with each other, it would automatically add the user_id into the database for projects?

Thanks!

---

Edit: Converted all trip to projects, so others needing help knows

Comment: You can save it in the controller action too.

Comment: Why don't you use association. Trip can belong to user and then you can do `current_user.trip.build(trip_params)`

Comment: @Deep, my version is better

Comment: @asiniy So if no association is there when he would be needing user's trip what would you like to do? `Trip.where(user_id: current_user.id)` or `current_user.trips`

Comment: That's another case. In this occasion, `trip_params` still can have user id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope. That shouldn't be in form, because of everybody can change hidden value at the form.

Assuming you are using strong parameters

```
def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)
  @project.save # or something else
end

def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(something_permitted_here)
    .merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

If you put user id on hidden form it will cause a breach in security. Because using browser tools a hacker can change the `user_id` and can inject information for other user. A better way is to put it into controller.

Comment: why would one downvote it when it states right things? upvoted

Answer (score 1):

Inside controller, you can do so:

```
def create
  @project.user = current_user
  @project.save
  #...
end
```

This way you protect yourself against someone manually changing the `user_id` in html.

Answer (score 1):

Use the association to your advantage:

```
def create
  @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
  if @project.save
  # ...etc
end
```